# CollapsingToolbarLayout - how to pin toolbar and another view but still have parralax for header image?

Tags: android, material-design

Lets take a look at what i would like to achieve first:

[image]

So the yellow area will be for text. it should not move. it should always be in a static position pinned. The toolbar should likewise also be static and always pinned.  But the blue part will have an image in it. It should shrink when scrolled and parallax.  so if user scrolls up the image should scroll up and eventually disappear with parallax.  I am having trouble getting the yellow area to not move.

if you need to know, below the blue area is a scrollView.

Just so you know, the yellow bar is actually a textview with match parent and yellow background, but it can be any view i suppose. Lets take a look at what i have done so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentScrim="@color/white"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:title="SHOPPING BAG"
    android:elevation="4dp"/>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_tax_rebate_msg"
        fontPath="fonts/Medium-Extd.otf"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bright_yellow"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="@string/tax_rebate_disclaimer"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="10sp"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_msg"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

//... rest if it is a scrollview, not important
```

so the problem im having with this again, is that the yellow area is moving when i scroll.  How do i make it so only the blue area shrinks when user scrolls ?the yellow area will have important info and should never be unseen by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Coordinator Layout Behaviors to achieve what you are looking for.

The basic idea is rather than setting the coordinator layout to do a default behavior for everything, you can fine grain every view by creating a custom behavior. In this way you can do some fancy things.

Comment: i checked it out but i dont see yet how it can help in this situation.